# Call C# Method using Javascript from ASP.Net with Parameters

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Can anyone help me call a C# method in the code behind using Javascript in an aspx page with parameters?

Here is the javascript I have that calls the sample() method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showModal(arr, hey) {
        '<%=sample(arr,hey)%>';
     }
</script>
```

I have this c# code to be called that has 2 parameters:

```
protected string sample(int i, string a)
{
    lblsample.Text =i + "," + a;
    return lblsample.Text;
}
```

This gave me an error on the Javascript code:

`arr does not exist in the current context`

By the way, the javascript will be executed when a particular bar in a chart is clicked. I use fusioncharts.

Here's the code on how to call and pass the parameters to the ShowModal javascript function:

```
xmlString.AppendFormat("<set label='{3}' value='{1}' tooltext='Employee: {0}{2}Hours:{1}' link='j-showModal-{1}, {1}'/>", dt.Rows[i][1].ToString(), dt.Rows[i][2].ToString(), "{br}", dt.Rows[i]["EmpNameDot"].ToString());
```

Comment: This is a classic misunderstanding of the difference between *client-side* and *server-side* code.  That JavaScript may execute after some event in the UI, but the C# code embedded within it executes *once* during the page load on the server before it even gets to the browser.  And when that *C# code* executes, the values `arr` and `hey` don't exist *server-side*.  What are you actually trying to accomplish?  Because whatever it is, the way you're trying to accomplish it is not correct.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. What I am trying to accomplish is that when the bar on the chart is clicked, the jacascript function showModal (with parameters) will be called which this javascript will call a C# method that will populate the gridview inside the modalpopupextender then will show the modalpopup

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on David's answer:
There are many ways to access the server-side from the client-side after the page is rendered.  A partial list and in no particular order:

- `WebMethod`
- `UpdatePanel`
- `ASMX` web service
- `WCF` web service
- `Web API`
- `SignalR`

The one you choose depends on what you are trying to achieve. In any case, you will need to make an `AJAX` request (this can be done very simply using `jQuery`) and handle the returned value in `JavaScript` code. It seems like you are using `WebForms`. An `UpdatePanel` is the `WebForms`-ish way of doing this. The `UpdatePanel` takes care of the ajax calls for you, you just need to set it up correctly.

**EDIT:** If you edit your question with a better explanation of what it is you are really trying to achieve, maybe I can provide a more operative answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix client-side and server-side code like that.  The server-side code runs *on the server* when the page is requested.  And at that time it has no knowledge of any client-side events or information.

Why are you trying to do this in server-side code anyway?  All you're doing is setting some text on a page element.  Just do that with JavaScript so you don't have to post back to the server.  Something like this:

```
function showModal(arr, hey) {
    document.getElementById('lblsample').textContent = arr + ',' + hey;
}
```

Note that this assumes a *client-side* `id` value of `lblsample` in your HTML.  That *might not* be the case.  You'll have to actually examine your HTML and check.  There is a workaround where server-side code can help, though.  You can embed some server-side code to run once at page load which will emit the client-side `id` for that element:

```
function showModal(arr, hey) {
    document.getElementById('<%=lblsample.ClientID%>').textContent = arr + ',' + hey;
}
```

Comment: the server-side code that will be called using javascript will populate a gridview inside a modalpopupextender then will show the modalpopupextender